# undefined index $_SESSION variable in PHP

Tags: php, variables, session

i have created a $_SESSION variable in a file named (cart.php) then i called this variable in another page (index.php) , it keeps showing this error :
UNDEFINED INDEX ON 'NbrCmd' in index.php meanwhile it's working in cart.php 
this is 'cart.php' variable declaration and 'echo' :

```
$nbrcmd = 3;
$_SESSION['nbrcmd_online'] = $nbrcmd;
```

this is index.php where i called this variable :

```
<p class="text-shopping-cart cart-total-full"> <?php echo $_SESSION['nbrcmd_online'] ; ?> </p>
```

the session is already started in the two files , and the index is right ! 
this code : `<?php echo $_SESSION['nbrcmd_online'] ; ?>`
works in cart.php but in index.php it's an undefined index .
please help and thanks

Comment: *Note:* The `session_start()` function must be the very first thing in your document. Before any HTML tags.

Comment: Please copy/paste the _exact_ error message you are getting.

Comment: If the session is started in both files, then this is an issue with undefined index in the array. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef. I imagine this is related to index.php not having the session variable set before going to cart.php.

Comment: Let's see the full code of the two files, please.

Comment: full error message 
( ! ) NOTICE: UNDEFINED INDEX: NBRCMD_ONLINE IN C:\WAMP64\WWW\LOOH\VIEWS\INDEX.PHP ON LINE 401

Comment: Guys using var_dump($_SESSION) i figured out that the two files dosen't have the same $_SESSION variables ! it's supposed to be one session started and one session variables no ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `session_start()` at the **top of your document**.

Also use `var_dump($_SESSION)` to find out what exactly is set as session.

Comment: The post says "the session is already started in the two files".  Barring proof to the contrary, I'd say OP is already doing what you're suggesting.

Comment: @PatrickQ true, but it's not sure where exactly he has started it.

Comment: That may be, but at this point, you're really just guessing, which makes this more of a comment than a real answer.

Comment: Guys when i used var dump $_SESSION it's not showing the variable that i created in cart.php !!!

Comment: the session is started and to check that out , i have put session_start() and it says session restarted

Comment: Guys using var_dump($_SESSION) i figured out that the two files dosen't have the same $_SESSION variables ! it's supposed to be one session started and one session variables no ?

Comment: @BechirGharsallah if `var_dump($_SESSION)` doesn't output the session with the key `nbrcmd_online`, you can be sure that either your session with the key `nbrcmd_online` could not be set or you unset the session, before you try to output the value of it. Make sure there is no `session_destroy()` in your script.

Answer (score 1):

add config.php file in variable:

session_start();

Comment: The post says "the session is already started in the two files".  Barring proof to the contrary, I'd say OP is already doing what you're suggesting.

Comment: If it is written in two files, clear cookies and cache and continue on a hidden tab if you are working on a project chrome browser.